# Issues regarding retreiving ERC 721 Transactions and them not showing up on the API action=tokennfttx endpoint

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, api

I'm currently attempting to retreive ERC 721 Transactions with Etherscan's API for a wallet and the most recent transactions are not showing up.
The request I am pushing is the following :"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokennfttx&address=0xb01d543249ef3287Bf8716D9B205426519f964D8&startblock=0&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken"

If you scroll all the way down the results, you will get the latest transaction's timestamp which is '1676607827'(February 17th), this is false.
As you can see, data is only showing up until the 17th of February 2023. I have tested this out by purchasing an NFT on Opensea on the 19th, I am able to view the transaction on the website but the endpoint is not pulling the transaction.

Would anyone know how to solve this issue or is it simply a problem regarding the actual API itself?

Comment: You should contact etherscan for enquires about their endpoints.